# How important is it to watch Farscape in order?

Tags: suggested-order, farscape

I just watched my first episode of Farscape last night (a random episode about being invaded by Klingon-like characters). Looking at the questions here, and browsing the Wikipedia article, it seems like there is a lot of plot building over several episodes and possibly seasons.

Should I make an effort to watch some or all episodes in order?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By all means, watch it in the correct order - there are several story arcs and sub-arcs, enemies turning into allies etc. which you will have a hard time to understand if you watch the episodes randomly (watching Farscape in the wrong order is still better than not watching it at all, but it will be so much more fun to watch it from start to end).

Answer (score 9):

Farscape becomes much more plot-arc heavy at the end of season 1.  S1E19, *Nerve*, begins the 4-episode season finale.  Those finale episodes have callbacks to episodes earlier in the season, but much of season 1 is composed of stand-alone episodes.  Season 2 then begins the plot-arc heavy trend.

So it's okay to watch most of season 1 out of order, but I'd say it's necessary to watch the later seasons in order.

Comment: I respectfully disagree - sequence in the first season might not be that important to the plot, is is however important in terms of character developement. If you've not been through five episodes of  Crichtons flippant behaviour you will not sufficently feel the impact when he concedes to Aeryn Sun that he "stands corrected" in PK Tech girl (no spoilers, go and watch it, it's brilliant). But I have obviously strong feeling about Farscape which is rarely conductive to a productive discussion so I think I'll shut up right here :-)

Comment: @EikePierstorff I agree there is character development in the first season, but due to the lack of plot elements that are referenced later, I simply find it acceptable to skip or watch out of order.  Especially since many of the early episodes are rough to watch.  The quality of the show definitely improves later on.

Comment: Although there's nothing arc-like, most episodes in the first season have one or two small references to prior episodes.  They're the type that add to the continuity if you spot them, but you don't really lose anything if you miss them.  I otherwise agree with @EikePierstorff that the character development is big enough to be off-putting if viewed largely in the wrong order - mixing up some nearby episodes wouldn't be too bad, though.

Comment: It looks like my own momentum has propelled me a bit off-tangent in the comment above. It is ouf course Aeryn who "stands corrected" in that Episode.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Yes it was Aeryn who voiced that revelation. That dialogue between Aeryn and Crichton was pivotal in their relationship.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind continuity errors, you *can* watch most of the episodes in the first season – except multi-part episodes, of course – in whatever order you want to. You should definitely watch the episodes in order, though. It is very rewarding that way – in the beginning mostly because of character development and a few episodes in also due to the story arcs.

Be advised that your best guide to watch the episodes in order is the production code which is shown on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Farscape_episodes) (There's also a list sorted by production code over at [Farscape World](http://www.farscapeworld.com/episodes/)). For instance, [I, E.T.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I,_E.T.) was intended to be the second episode but it was aired as the seventh. It's not really troubling but if you're an observant watcher, you will notice some discrepancies. Some DVD and Blu-Rays sets are also out of order because they used the order the episodes were originally aired.

There's also a [Skip It/Watch It](http://liztellsfrank.com/2012/04/03/farscape-the-complete-skip-itwatch-it-guide/) guide that can help you out if you're in a hurry. I don't necessarily agree with some of the suggestions but let me be clear on that: *Jeremiah Crichton* definitely is the worst episode Farscape has to offer. I advise against skipping any episode. Most episodes considered skipable give quite a bit of backstory or hint at something that's further explored in future episodes.

**TL;DR**
That being said, it's easier to watch every episode in the intended viewing order than trying to determine what episode you can safely skip or watch later without being confused. If you don't mind continuity, you can watch the first dozen episodes or so out of order. Be advised, there are almost no stand-alone episodes later on so you shouldn't even think about going that route. Under no circumstances mix up the viewing order of the multi-part episodes!