# What is the intended viewing order for Farscape?

Tags: suggested-order, farscape

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/44849/20840) already asks what about the importance of watching Farscape in the intended order, but unfortunately the only answer that offers an intended order recommends going by the production code, which I am skeptical about (see below).

So far, I have found four possible viewing orders and no straightforward answer:

- **[By production code](http://www.farscapeworld.com/episodes/index.php?sort=prod)** – So far I watched almost all of Season 1 in this order, and it made sense. Obviously, there is some natural order for the last third of the season (after *Durka Returns),* but the subtle character developments and details in the first two thirds also seemed to fit. What was a little bit bizarre is that some similarly themed episodes were directly succeeding each other without apparent reason. Most importantly, I spotted that the serial *Look at the Princess* would be torn apart and rearranged in this order, which makes me skeptical about continuing that order.
- **[By UK airdate](http://www.farscapeworld.com/episodes/index.php?sort=ukaired)** or **[by US airdate](http://www.farscapeworld.com/episodes/index.php?sort=usaired)** – Outside of Season 1, these differ only by one episode *(My Three Crichtons).* In Seasons 3 and 4, they only differ from the production-code order in one case (flipping *Lava's a Many Splendored Thing* and *Promises)*. However, in Season 1, they put *I, E.T.* (the second episode by production-code order) rather late, which does not seem to fit the subtle character developments to me. There are also a lot of differences to the production-code order in season 2, which I cannot comment on.
- **[By Henson.com](http://www.henson.com/fantasy_scifi.php?content=farscape)** – In Season 1, this is identical to the production-code order; in Season 2, it differs only be putting *Look at the Princess II* where one would expect it. In the other seasons it follows the production-code order. This order is my best guess so far, but only a guess.

So, my question is: **Is any of the above the intended viewing order, and if not, what is?** And as a bonus: Where should the bonus episode *Union* be placed?

*I am primarily interested in Season 2 and onwards and have already seen most of Season 1, but I would prefer to have the answers free from unmarked spoilers for the sake of others.*

Comment: Intended by whom?

Comment: There's no magical answer for this, nor will you really gain any additional enjoyment out of the series by watching them in some sort of weird [machete order](http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2015/12/28/machete-order-update-and-faq/).

Comment: @Richard: I am not asking for the **best** viewing order, I am asking for the order as **intended** by the creators? (If there should be no such viewing order, i.e., if even the creators disagree on in which order the series should be viewed, I would consider this an answer as well.) There is nothing magical about this.

Comment: You've already got the production codes and the listing from Henson.com (e.g. the creators). That's the order they're found on the DVDs, which you already know.

Comment: @Richard: Actually, on my DVDs, they are in one of the airing orders, for whatever it’s worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the Starburst Edition DVDs, and the order the series is on that set feels right to me. I'm in the U.S., and would say definitely not to follow the U.S. airing order. The only problem I have with the Henson.com order is with "Dream a Little Dream". It was intended to open season two, but was changed to go later in the season (as "Re: Union"). When they made that change, they inserted scenes to make the main story play as a flashback. With these scenes, it feels a bit screwy to watch it at the start of season two, before we know the fates of the characters after season one's cliffhanger. If your version doesn't have those extra scenes, then it's fine to start season two with it.